# How to save column when you group by another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the dataset with top 100 richest people in the world.
[image]
I want to group by "age" column, leave only max value in "net_worth" and have the third column - "name" of this person.
I could make two columns with code

```
df = df.groupby(['age']).agg({'net_worth': ['max']})
```

[image]
I want to have third column "name", but I don't know how to do it

I tried

```
df = df.groupby(['age', 'name']).agg({'net_worth': ['max']})
```

But 'name' column involved in group.
I need smth like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with extract numbers from `net_worth` by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
s = df['net_worth'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
out = df.loc[s.groupby(df['age']).idxmax(),['net_worth','name','age']]
print (out.head())
      net_worth             name   age
90  $18 Billion     Lukas Walton  36.0
92  $17 Billion      Pavel Durov  37.0
17  $70 Billion  Mark Zuckerberg  38.0
30  $44 Billion     Zhang Yiming  39.0
82  $19 Billion  Eduardo Saverin  40.0
```